# Redirect file descriptor into memory

Tags: c, posix, memory-mapped-files, circular-buffer

I am working with a file API that only provides a `const char* filename` interface (accepting `-` for `stdout`) when writing files. I would instead like the output to be written into memory, so I can then pass the data elsewhere.

I can use `dup2` to redirect `stdout` to an arbitrary file descriptor and something like `fmemopen`/`open_memstream` as my sink. However, the memory stream functions expect a size, which -- in my case -- I don't know in advance and could be arbitrarily large.

The data I need to access, however, does have a fixed length and offset within what's being produced (e.g., out of 1MB, I need the 64KB starting at 384KB, etc.). As such, is there a way to set up a circular buffer with `fmemopen`/`open_memstream` that just keeps being rewritten until reaching the offset in question? (I realise this is inefficient, but there's no ability to seek.)

Or is this the wrong approach? I've read a bit about memory mapped files and that seems to be similar to what I'm trying to achieve, but it's not something I know much about...

---

*EDIT* Just to be clear, I cannot write anything to disk.

Comment: How about portability? Using `/dev/fd/?` and reading in a different thread/process comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks, @Diego: That approach works and was pretty easy to implement. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it (providing no better suggestions appear in the meantime!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dup2` redirect `stdout` to a pipe and call the API with `-` to instruct it to use standard output. Then read from the pipe the data generated by the API, filter it and store it in a memory region.

If the pipe capacity is not enough, you will need two threads to make this approach work.

One will be running the API call generating data and putting it into the pipe.

The other thread, will take the data from the pipe, check the offset and store the data in memory when the target offset is reached. But keep reading from the pipe until EOF so that the other thread can complete the API call and finish gracefully.